# get_text doesn't work for a div tag

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am scraping this website: https://icodrops.com/quarkchain/

I want to get the date the token sale ended, which is "14 February". This is stored in a div tag with the class "sale-date". However, when I call ".get_text" on this div tag, I get this:

```
<bound method Tag.get_text of <div class="sale-date">14 February</div>>
```

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = requests.get("https://icodrops.com/quarkchain/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

pt1 = soup.find(class_ = "white-desk ico-desk")
date = pt1.find(class_= "sale-date").get_text

print(date)
```

Are there any other ways I can extract the text inside the div tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. You forgot to use `()` at the end of `.get_text` which should be `.get_text()`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = requests.get("https://icodrops.com/quarkchain/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
date = soup.find(class_= "sale-date").get_text()
print(date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
date = pt1.find(class_= "sale-date").get_text
```

To:

```
date = pt1.find(class_= "sale-date").get_text()
```